# Problems with diacritics in Ancient Greek

Tags: xetex, unicode, accents, greek

I need to type a special Greek character in LaTeX (I use XeLaTeX), but I don't know how do it.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.8cm,bottom=0.5cm,footskip=0.1cm,headsep=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{epltxfn}
\setmainfont{KadmosU}
\usepackage{covington} 
\makeatletter
\usepackage{url}
\pagenumbering{Roman}



\begin{document}

ῐ̔́


ῑ̔́

\twoacc['|\={ι}]

\twoacc[\'|\={ι}]





\end{document}
```

I want to type the first and the second (I just pasted it from Wikipedia), for the last two I use the package "convington", but I did not found where I can combine three diacritics (I just can do this with two!).

So, I want to know a way to put three (even more) diacritics.

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361071/125871) answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the KadmosU font doesn't seem to be free.

Comment: @SandyG , Unfortunately, I need to use a specific font for the package in question, I want to know if have a general method that works with all fonts that supports  the symbol (Like: KadmosU, Linux Libertine O, New Athena  Unicode e etc.)

Comment: @egreg  I found this font at  < https://fonts2u.com/kadmosu.font > and is free for personal use. Although is not open access :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to find the correct tune up for each combination. The `\kk` macro adds kerning to fix the relative positions of the top accents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% since I don't have the font installed on my system, I placed it in the working directory
\setmainfont{KadmosU}[Extension=.ttf,Path=./]
% use the following line if you have it among the system fonts
%\setmainfont{KadmosU}

% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361120/4427
\DeclareRobustCommand{\combinedaccent}[2]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \hidewidth#1\hidewidth\relax\cr
      \noalign{\vskip -1ex}
      #2\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\dasia}{\raisebox{0.15ex}{\symbol{"A0}\symbol{"0314}}}
\newcommand{\psili}{\raisebox{0.15ex}{\symbol{"A0}\symbol{"0313}}}
\newcommand{\barys}{\symbol{"A0}\symbol{"0300}}
\newcommand{\oxys}{\symbol{"A0}\symbol{"0301}}
\newcommand{\kk}[1]{\kern#1em\relax}


\begin{document}

\combinedaccent{\dasia\oxys\kk{-0.15}}{\u{ι}}
\combinedaccent{\dasia\oxys\kk{-0.15}}{\={ι}}
\combinedaccent{\dasia\oxys\kk{-0.15}}{\={ι}}
\combinedaccent{\kk{0.15}\psili}{\={ι}}
\combinedaccent{\kk{0.25}\oxys}{\={ι}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I just paste your answer but did not work in my XeLaTeX. He said: "Archive not found", and appeared white pdf... I did not what happen...

Comment: @BozenoBozilson I used `[Extension=.ttf,Path=./]` to adjust for my system. You probably have KadmosU installed as a system font so you don't need that part.